# Best way to get values from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a dict:

```
d = {'A': {'field': 1}, 'B': {'field': 2}}
```

How can I list the values of all `field` keys? Expected result:

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one line simply with list comprehension like so:

```
fields = [x["field"] for x in d.values() if 'field' in x.keys()]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! Let's say I have a 3rd item, `C` which doesn't contain `field`. How can I "ignore" that?

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it check conditionally whether it exists. If `field` does not exist, it will just skip it.

Answer (score 2):

```
[value['field'] for _, value in d.items() if 'field' in value]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> d
{'A': {'field': 1}, 'B': {'field': 2}}
>>> [d[e]['field'] for e in d]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clearer readable code than one-liners:

```py
d = {'A': {'field': 1}, 'B': {'field': 2}}
fields = d.values()
result = []
for val in fields:
  result.append(val['field'])

print(result)
```

[Repl link](https://repl.it/repls/SeagreenLameAttributes)